# Why does subtracting a pointer value from an address result in gap of 8 times the pointer value?

Tags: c, pointers, types, type-conversion

In the following snippet, pointer addresses and values are referenced as the type `size_t`.
However as the title says, the last subtraction does not make sense to me. It acts like, as if it subtracts the number multiplied with 8 instead of the actual value as seen in the `int array`.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

int main()
{
    int i[6] = {2, 0, 1, 0, 20, 24};

    void *ptr = &i[2];

    printf("%zu\n", ((size_t*)ptr));
    printf("%zu\n", *((size_t*)ptr));
    printf("%zu\n", ((size_t*)ptr) - *((size_t*)ptr));
}
```

Comment: What type of specifier is `%zu`?  Giving warning on my compiler: `Unknown conversion type character 'z' in format`.

Comment: @haccks It is the correct conversion specifier for `size_t`.

Comment: @haccks  `z` is a modifier for integer formats indicating the expected type of the integer parameter is `size_t`.  IMHO it is not used correctly here. (C11 7.21.6.1 7)

Comment: @Jimbo It's not a GNU extension, it's a standard specifier, present in C99 and later.

Comment: @chux That's exactly right, it's (ab)used for a `size_t *` whereas it would expect a `size_t`.

Comment: @H2CO3: thanks for letting me know, will read up on that one! Have deleted comment.

Comment: @H2CO3; It is giving error on **GCC 4.7.1** (C99 mode)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First thing to note is that you're accessing a signed integer variable through a pointer to an unsigned integer variable. Also note that `sizeof(size_t)` may not necessarily equal `sizeof(int)`!

The line:

```
printf("%zu\n", ((size_t*)ptr) - *((size_t*)ptr));
```

Effectively Does `AddressOf(i[2]) - i[2]`, which is `AddressOf(i[2]) - 1`.

In C pointer arithmetic the address is decremented not by 1, but by `1 * sizeof(data type)`, which is whatever `sizeof(size_t)` is on your machine. If you're on a 64-bit machine this could be 8 bytes. This the address you get will be `-8` and not, as I think you're expecting, `-1`...

EDIT: The `%z` could probably be `%p` for *pointer* addresses. The casts to `size_t *` are not needed and could be dangerous as discussed above...

Comment: Great, I had no idea it multiplied the value with sizeof(datatype). Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please do **not** answer questions that are obviously duplicates. Vote for closure instead.

Answer (score 0):

You are subtracting `i[2] == 1` from a `size_t` pointer, so the actual difference is `sizeof(size_t) == 8`.